# proving function is not continuous at a point using Cauchy definition of continuity

Tags: calculus

$g(x)$ is a function continuous at $_0$ and $()=()()$ when $()$ is Dirichlet Function. $(0)≠0$.

if $_0∈ℚ$ then let $=∣(_0)∣$, then for every $>0$, I choose $∉ℚ$ that $∣−_0∣<$ I get $∣()−(_0)∣=∣()∗0−(_0)∗1∣=∣(_0)∣≥$

but if $_0∉ℚ$ I can't find  that for every $>0$ if I choose x that $∣−_0∣<$ I get $∣()−(_0)∣≥$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x_0 \not \in \mathbb{Q}$, take $\epsilon = \frac{|g(x_0)|}{2}$. Since $g$ is continuous, we can find $\delta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ $|x-x_0| \leq \delta$ implies $|g(x)-g(x_0)| \leq \epsilon$. The triangle inequality then yields $|g(x)| \geq \epsilon$. Now, any rational $x$ that is closer than $\delta$ to $x_0$ will give $|g(x)D(x)-g(x_0)D(x_0)| = |g(x)| \geq \epsilon$.